# Looking up matching cell data based on a common ID

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Let me preface this by saying that I'm very much unfamiliar with Excel formulas.
I only have a basic knowledge, and it has been years since I have used it at all.

I have two different sets of columns in my Excel worksheet, each having an ID and a name.
Now I want to use a formula to generate a string that contains the matching cell values from both datasets, where the IDs match.

Since the second dataset doesn't necessarily have matching information for each item of the first dataset, I only want to generate the strings for each item of the second dataset.

Below is a screenshot of a simplified example detailing what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: A basic example]

I have looked at VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, but I'm unsure if or how I can get to the solution I want with those.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. if the records are the same in both table 1 and table 2, it returns `Value unchanged`, if the record exists only on table 2 but not on table 1, it returns `Value not in original table`. Let me know if you need to change this behavior.

```
=IFNA(IF(E2=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$7,0)),"Value unchanged", "Record "&D2&" changed from "&E2&" to "&INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$7,0))),"Value not in original table")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add another column to set 2, which is a vlookup to see if the ID is found in set 1.

Formula for column F:

```
    Cell F2: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE),"not found")
```

Then, here's your formula for column G:

```
    Cell G2: =IF(F2="not found","Record "&D2&" not found in first set",IF(E2<>F2,"Record "&D2&" changes from "&F2&" to "&E2,"Record " &D2& " does not change"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This satisfies the brief as given, but assumes that if the ID exists it has changed name.

[image]

Formula is cell G2 is

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$6,0)),"","Record " & D2 & " changes from " & INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$6,0))) & " to " & E2
```